# How to insert multiline text into a column of the PostgreSQL table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm looking for a way to insert a multiline text into PostgreSQL table (column).

[Screenshot of the insert query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnRjx.png)

Suppose I have a table 'problem' within the data.sql file, and I want to insert a multiline text into DETAILS column.
What should I do?

Comment: Please no screenshots of code. Copy it and paste it. Highlight what was pasted and click the `{}` button in the editor to format it as code so whitespace and line-feeds are preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [String Constants With C-Style Escapes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE) by adding an `E` before the text constant, then an `\n` wherever you want a newline: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/DhesfTjh)

```
create table test(id serial primary key, a text);
insert into test (a) values (E'line1\nline2\nline3') returning *;
```

| id | a |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | line1 line2 line3 |